# Windows process handle count continues to grow

Tags: c++, windows, windbg

I'm working on a C++ project on Windows 10, its been noticed that over time the Handles associated with the process increases and continues to grow.

Searching online for a reason I'm not sure if this means that the process has a memory leak or if this is normal.

When memory is allocated and then freed, would I see the handles increase and decrease?

I've been using this as I'm struggling to find what the cause is:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/markrussinovich/pushing-the-limits-of-windows-handles

I cannot find any calls to anything that creates a handle in the code.

[Edit] Using windbg to open the dumped process content:

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 10.0.18362.1 X86
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Loading Dump File [C:\Users\u49100\Downloads\ManagementServiceGroup.dmp]
User Mini Dump File with Full Memory: Only application data is available

Symbol search path is: srv*
Executable search path is: 
Windows 10 Version 16299 MP (4 procs) Free x86 compatible
Product: WinNt, suite: SingleUserTS
16299.637.x86fre.rs3_release_svc.180808-1748
Machine Name:
Debug session time: Wed Feb  5 09:56:54.000 2020 (UTC + 0:00)
System Uptime: 0 days 0:44:55.871
Process Uptime: 0 days 0:02:30.000
................................................................
.....................................
This dump file has a breakpoint exception stored in it.
The stored exception information can be accessed via .ecxr.
For analysis of this file, run !analyze -v
eax=002f1000 ebx=00000000 ecx=7707a080 edx=7707a080 esi=7707a080 edi=7707a080
eip=77041900 esp=0d24ff54 ebp=0d24ff80 iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na pe nc
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000244
ntdll!DbgBreakPoint:
77041900 cc              int     3
0:075> !analyze -v
ERROR: FindPlugIns 8007007b
ERROR: Some plugins may not be available [8007007b]
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Exception Analysis                                   *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for PlatformSG.dll
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for ManagementServiceGroup.exe
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for SlaveCommsSG.dll
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for CalibrationFramework.dll
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for SPLINTServer.dll
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for TCPIPManager.dll
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for MillikanFaults.dll
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for MillikanCalibration.dll
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for HBC.dll
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for Machine.dll
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for Vibrator.dll
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for TelnetServer.dll
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for UserDefects.dll
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for HBCStatCollector.dll
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for StatisticsArchiver.dll
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for SplintVibratorCalibration.dll
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for StatisticsHistorian.dll
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for ModeManager.dll
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for SPLINTStatDistributor.dll
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for IOMillikan.dll
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for ProcessControlSG.dll
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for CameraGroup.dll
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for ComponentLifeMonitor.dll

KEY_VALUES_STRING: 1

    Key  : Timeline.OS.Boot.DeltaSec
    Value: 2695

    Key  : Timeline.Process.Start.DeltaSec
    Value: 150

PROCESSES_ANALYSIS: 1

SERVICE_ANALYSIS: 1

STACKHASH_ANALYSIS: 1

TIMELINE_ANALYSIS: 1

Timeline: !analyze.Start
    Name: <blank>
    Time: 2020-02-05T10:01:43.660Z
    Diff: 289660 mSec

Timeline: Dump.Current
    Name: <blank>
    Time: 2020-02-05T09:56:54.0Z
    Diff: 0 mSec

Timeline: Process.Start
    Name: <blank>
    Time: 2020-02-05T09:54:24.0Z
    Diff: 150000 mSec

Timeline: OS.Boot
    Name: <blank>
    Time: 2020-02-05T09:11:59.0Z
    Diff: 2695000 mSec

DUMP_CLASS: 2

DUMP_QUALIFIER: 400

CONTEXT:  (.ecxr)
eax=002f1000 ebx=00000000 ecx=7707a080 edx=7707a080 esi=7707a080 edi=7707a080
eip=77041900 esp=0d24ff54 ebp=0d24ff80 iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na pe nc
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000244
ntdll!DbgBreakPoint:
77041900 cc              int     3
Resetting default scope

FAULTING_IP: 
ntdll!DbgBreakPoint+0
77041900 cc              int     3

EXCEPTION_RECORD:  (.exr -1)
ExceptionAddress: 77041900 (ntdll!DbgBreakPoint)
   ExceptionCode: 80000003 (Break instruction exception)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000000
NumberParameters: 1
   Parameter[0]: 00000000

PROCESS_NAME:  ManagementServiceGroup.exe

ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0x80000003 - {EXCEPTION}  Breakpoint  A breakpoint has been reached.

EXCEPTION_CODE: (HRESULT) 0x80000003 (2147483651) - One or more arguments are invalid

EXCEPTION_CODE_STR:  80000003

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER1:  00000000

WATSON_BKT_PROCSTAMP:  5e38030b

WATSON_BKT_MODULE:  ntdll.dll

WATSON_BKT_MODSTAMP:  7b4896c1

WATSON_BKT_MODOFFSET:  71900

WATSON_BKT_MODVER:  10.0.16299.936

MODULE_VER_PRODUCT:  Microsoft® Windows® Operating System

BUILD_VERSION_STRING:  16299.637.x86fre.rs3_release_svc.180808-1748

MODLIST_WITH_TSCHKSUM_HASH:  70177fe8843802a721ebc9381c39ea0930d91d47

MODLIST_SHA1_HASH:  88c13d9b0d70b5ff412cbabd039482499bc59744

NTGLOBALFLAG:  1100

PROCESS_BAM_CURRENT_THROTTLED: 0

PROCESS_BAM_PREVIOUS_THROTTLED: 0

APPLICATION_VERIFIER_FLAGS:  80000004

CHKIMG_EXTENSION: !chkimg -lo 50 -d !ntdll
    77030eb0-77030eb4  5 bytes - ntdll!LdrLoadDll
      [ 8b ff 55 8b ec:e9 9b 68 8c fc ]
    7703f780-7703f784  5 bytes - ntdll!NtAllocateVirtualMemory (+0xe8d0)
      [ b8 18 00 00 00:e9 0b 69 8b fc ]
    7703f800-7703f804  5 bytes - ntdll!NtFreeVirtualMemory (+0x80)
      [ b8 1e 00 00 00:e9 eb 6c 8b fc ]
    7703f8a0-7703f8a4  5 bytes - ntdll!NtMapViewOfSection (+0xa0)
      [ b8 28 00 00 00:e9 5b 77 8b fc ]
    7703f8c0-7703f8c4  5 bytes - ntdll!NtUnmapViewOfSection (+0x20)
      [ b8 2a 00 00 00:e9 cb 7b 8b fc ]
    7703f9c0-7703f9c4  5 bytes - ntdll!NtWriteVirtualMemory (+0x100)
      [ b8 3a 00 00 00:e9 bb 73 8b fc ]
    7703fa10-7703fa14  5 bytes - ntdll!NtReadVirtualMemory (+0x50)
      [ b8 3f 00 00 00:e9 ab 74 8b fc ]
    7703fa70-7703fa74  5 bytes - ntdll!NtQueueApcThread (+0x60)
      [ b8 45 00 00 00:e9 cb 7b 8b fc ]
    7703fb20-7703fb24  5 bytes - ntdll!NtProtectVirtualMemory (+0xb0)
      [ b8 50 00 00 00:e9 db 6a 8b fc ]
    7703fd80-7703fd84  5 bytes - ntdll!NtAlpcConnectPort (+0x260)
      [ b8 76 00 00 00:e9 ab 89 8b fc ]
    77040e30-77040e34  5 bytes - ntdll!NtSetContextThread (+0x10b0)
      [ b8 81 01 00 00:e9 eb 76 8b fc ]
    77041290-77041294  5 bytes - ntdll!NtWaitForDebugEvent (+0x460)
      [ b8 c7 01 00 00:e9 7b 00 8d fc ]
    77041930-77041934  5 bytes - ntdll!KiUserApcDispatcher (+0x6a0)
      [ 83 3d 98 77 0e:e9 2b 82 91 fc ]
65 errors : !ntdll (77030eb0-77041934)

PRODUCT_TYPE:  1

SUITE_MASK:  272

DUMP_FLAGS:  c07

DUMP_TYPE:  3

APPLICATION_VERIFIER_LOADED: 1

ANALYSIS_SESSION_HOST:  HW-WOP-113835

ANALYSIS_SESSION_TIME:  02-05-2020 10:01:43.0660

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 10.0.18362.1 x86fre

THREAD_ATTRIBUTES: 
ADDITIONAL_DEBUG_TEXT:  Followup set based on attribute [Is_ChosenCrashFollowupThread] from Frame:[0] on thread:[PSEUDO_THREAD]

OS_LOCALE:  ENG

BUGCHECK_STR:  MEMORY_CORRUPTION_PATCH_AVRF

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  MEMORY_CORRUPTION_PATCH_AVRF

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  MEMORY_CORRUPTION

PROBLEM_CLASSES: 

    ID:     [0n98]
    Type:   [AVRF]
    Class:  Addendum
    Scope:  DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID (Failure Bucket ID prefix)
            BUCKET_ID
    Name:   Add
    Data:   Omit
    PID:    [0x4254]
    TID:    [0x445c]
    Frame:  [0] : ntdll!DbgBreakPoint

    ID:     [0n209]
    Type:   [MEMORY_CORRUPTION]
    Class:  Primary
    Scope:  DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID (Failure Bucket ID prefix)
            BUCKET_ID
    Name:   Add
    Data:   Omit
    PID:    [0x4254]
    TID:    [0x445c]
    Frame:  [Unspecified]

    ID:     [0n157]
    Type:   [PATCH]
    Class:  Addendum
    Scope:  DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID (Failure Bucket ID prefix)
            BUCKET_ID
    Name:   Add
    Data:   Omit
    PID:    [0x4254]
    TID:    [0x445c]
    Frame:  [Unspecified]

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from 7707a0b9 to 77041900

STACK_TEXT:  
00000000 00000000 memory_corruption!ntdll+0x0


STACK_COMMAND:  ** Pseudo Context ** ManagedPseudo ** Value: 173e49f0 ** ; kb

THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD_FUNC:  646019e7612e819fc8aba56460d68e5912f8f117

THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD_FUNC_OFFSET:  70e2aeaf8a93e9fa2f653f0a0ed9deec52e32f7e

THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD:  7da7fbec386ce361a40d03d69a994bc4836f03e8

SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  0

SYMBOL_NAME:  memory_corruption!ntdll

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  0

BUCKET_ID:  MEMORY_CORRUPTION_PATCH_AVRF_memory_corruption!ntdll

FAILURE_EXCEPTION_CODE:  80000003

IMAGE_NAME:  memory_corruption

FAILURE_IMAGE_NAME:  memory_corruption

BUCKET_ID_IMAGE_STR:  memory_corruption

MODULE_NAME: memory_corruption

FAILURE_MODULE_NAME:  memory_corruption

BUCKET_ID_MODULE_STR:  memory_corruption

FAILURE_FUNCTION_NAME:  ntdll

BUCKET_ID_FUNCTION_STR:  ntdll

BUCKET_ID_OFFSET:  0

BUCKET_ID_MODTIMEDATESTAMP:  0

BUCKET_ID_MODCHECKSUM:  0

BUCKET_ID_MODVER_STR:  0.0.0.0

BUCKET_ID_PREFIX_STR:  

FAILURE_PROBLEM_CLASS:  MEMORY_CORRUPTION

FAILURE_SYMBOL_NAME:  memory_corruption!ntdll

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  MEMORY_CORRUPTION_PATCH_AVRF_80000003_memory_corruption!ntdll

TARGET_TIME:  2020-02-05T09:56:54.000Z

OSBUILD:  16299

OSSERVICEPACK:  1146

SERVICEPACK_NUMBER: 0

OS_REVISION: 0

OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x86

OSNAME:  Windows 10

OSEDITION:  Windows 10 WinNt SingleUserTS

USER_LCID:  0

OSBUILD_TIMESTAMP:  2014-08-09 10:57:59

BUILDDATESTAMP_STR:  180808-1748

BUILDLAB_STR:  rs3_release_svc

BUILDOSVER_STR:  10.0.16299.637.x86fre.rs3_release_svc.180808-1748

ANALYSIS_SESSION_ELAPSED_TIME:  1c133

ANALYSIS_SOURCE:  UM

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  um:memory_corruption_patch_avrf_80000003_memory_corruption!ntdll

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {fff25d61-b919-7e8b-df9e-56dec8271fe1}

Followup:     MachineOwner
---------
```

This doesn't mean a lot to me, if anyone has expertise in how to interpret this, your input would be very much appreciated.

[Edit 18-02-2020 Another dump and windbg output]

```
    Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 10.0.18362.1 X86
    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.        

    Loading Dump File [D:\Stuff\ManagementServiceGroup.dmp]
    User Mini Dump File with Full Memory: Only application data is available

    Symbol search path is: srv*
    Executable search path is: 
    Windows 10 Version 14393 MP (2 procs) Free x86 compatible
    Product: WinNt, suite: SingleUserTS
    10.0.14393.2430 (rs1_release_inmarket_aim.180806-1810)
    Machine Name:
    Debug session time: Tue Feb 18 10:22:54.000 2020 (UTC + 0:00)
    System Uptime: 0 days 0:41:07.933
    Process Uptime: 0 days 0:40:15.000
    ...............................................................................................
    For analysis of this file, run !analyze -v
    eax=0000000d ebx=00000000 ecx=0014f96c edx=775d53d0 esi=00000001 edi=00000001
    eip=775d53d0 esp=0014f96c ebp=0014fb00 iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na pe cy
    cs=001b  ss=0023  ds=0023  es=0023  fs=003b  gs=0000             efl=00000247
    ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet:
    775d53d0 c3              ret
```

Comment: This indicates a handle leak, you can use [`!htrace`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/-htrace) from [windbg](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/debugger-download-tools) to track handle allocation and find leaks, there are many articles that guide you on how to do this https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/jeff_dailey/Understanding-handle-leaks-and-how-to-use-htrace-to-find-them, what kind of handles are these? A common problem is calling the wrong function to close a handle, duplicating a handle and keeping the duplicate alive etc..

Comment: I'm not sure you'll see an immediate decrease in handles when you free them, but they should not continue to grow. I usually create some RAII wrappers around the handles to keep track of them.

Comment: Just to clarify: a memory leak leaks memory. A handle leak leaks handles. The functions used to manipulate them differ; in the case of a handle leak you're probably missing a `CloseHandle`. In C++ the two can get mixed up when you leak an object whose destructor would call `CloseHandle`. The OS doesn't care why you forgot to call `CloseHandle` though.

Comment: @EdChum-ReinstateMonica, I've install windbg and run through the video, unfortunately it hasn't found anything.

Comment: You could use [procmon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) just to see what handles are being opened and whether you see any corresponding close calls. So you're saying that calling `!htrace` then !htrace -enable`, run your program, brake in windbg and enter `!htrace -diff` shows no handles still open?

Comment: So first step is to establish the types of handles that are still open, then to determine who is opening such handles

Comment: @EdChum-ReinstateMonica, Thank you, procmon is so useful it's highlighted areas of concern which I will now investigate.

Comment: @EdChum-ReinstateMonica, "Process Monitor" has shown an Operation "QueryNameInformationFile" with a Result of "BUFFER OVERFLOW".  I can see from the Detail that the content is cut short, however I'm now trying to find out what is occuring.  Just found this: https://superuser.com/questions/491597/process-monitor-entrys-with-buffer-overflow, does this mean that the BUFFER OVERFLOW isn't a problem?

Comment: That link refers to the common practice of calling QueryNameInformationFile twice, you first pass an initial buffer, you then get told the actual size, then you call it again. If windbg is not showing anything you can try appverifier: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/mattn/tracking-handle-misuse-using-application-verifier-and-windbg. Although this blog post is old, the same guidance is relevant, download application verifier, then set your process as the target, it has numerous useful flags you can set to track a specific scenario, one of which is handles

Comment: @EdChum-ReinstateMonica, see rather big edit, I'm really not sure what this output is saying.

Comment: The result of the analysis is that it thinks there is a memory corruption, this may explain why you are leaking handles, to get sensible call stacks, you should once attached with windbg execute the following command: `.symfix;.reload;g`, this should resolve call stacks, if not add the paths using 'File->Symbol file path..' and browse to your pdbs, this assumes your pdbs have sufficient debugging information in them, you can also add a path to the source files. I would google to look for terms windbg memory corruption, this should give useful links. You can also try debugdiag, and appverifier

Comment: @EdChum-ReinstateMonica, I've tried this but not getting much, perhaps I've missed a step?  All I see is a couple of lines in windbg: (2940.b3c): C++ EH exception - code e06d7363 (first chance)
(2940.b3c): C++ EH exception - code e06d7363 (first chance)

Comment: first chance exception can be normal, you can break on these types of exceptions, from the menu 'Debug->Event Filters', then for 'C++ EH exception', modify from 'Disabled' to 'Enabled' and to 'Handled', this will break in Windbg. If it's something to not be concerned with, then you can revert the settings, (make a note of the original settings). I think's worth trying debugdiag first as it's easier to use for a high level view, then use appverifier, and turn on any verifier flags you think are worth looking at, and use in tandem with windbg

Comment: I suggest using Process Explorer as a live tool, not Process Monitor. It has a feature called "Lower Pane", which can show handles. It will list the type and most important information. I also doubt `!htrace` will be helpful in the beginning.It will be useful later, when you need to find the stack trace. First, I would try to find out what types of handles are leaking. In WinDbg `!handle` should reveal how many there are of which type, similar to Process Explorer.

Comment: @ThomasWeller, thank you, is there a way to report the number of Handles of each type for example I can see in TaskManger the number of threads is stable and not growing, but there are a lot of handles...which could be Events, Semaphore, File etc?

Comment: Exactly, Semaphores, Events, Files, Registry Keys etc. are all objects that are guarded by the Kernel. You don't have direct access to them, because they live in kernel space. A handle is an identifier for such a kernel object. I don't know a tool that could record handles by type over time. Even the performance monitor only has them overall as "handle count" (in group "process").

Comment: @ThomasWeller, I'm not making much progress with "Process Explorer", the process shows as a single entry under "cmd.exe", if I use right click select "Create Dump" then "Create Full Dump..." I specify a file name, eg. simon.dmp, I get an error dialog containing "Error configuring dump resources: The system cannot find the file specified." then it creates a 0 byte file in the selected folder using the name I supplied.

Comment: Do not create a dump. Select the process and press `Ctrl+H`. This should open a list of handles where you can see the type

Comment: Does windbg suspend a process whilst it is attached?  I'm finding that whilst windbg is attached to the process that nothing else can connect to the same process, but if I connect other applications before windbg then its ok, but after connecting windbg communication is suspended.

Comment: @EdChum-ReinstateMonica, thank you for your time and assistance, I'm well on the way to a fix.

Comment: No worries, this stuff gets hairy pretty quickly but it's a good learning experience

Comment: @ThomasWeller, just revisiting this issue, I'm running Process Explorer, I have selected the process and when I try to create a full dump I get:  "Error opening process: Access is denied."

Comment: We're talking about different things: I want you to analyze handles in Process Explorer, you want to create a crash dump in Process Explorer. Anyway, try running it as administrator (File/Show Details of all processes). If that does not help, the process is protected and you might need to run Process Explorer as NT-AUTHORITY\SYSTEM

Comment: @ThomasWeller, I have the full dmp file now, will take a look with windbg.

Comment: @ThomasWeller, where do I press Ctrl+H, what application is this being done in?  I tried whilst Process Monitor is up and it invokes the Process Monitor Highlighting dialog.

Comment: @ThomasWeller, what application?

Comment: Yep, done that now...lots of data, can I export this?

Comment: `Ctrl+A`. Maybe you want to know your tools: https://www.amazon.de/dp/073565672X

Comment: @ThomasWeller, I've saved the data, now something to analyse the file would be very useful, the list contains lots of 'Event', 'Semaphore', 'Thread'

Comment: @ThomasWeller, just purchased: https://www.amazon.co.uk/Windows-Sysinternals-Administrators-Reference-Russinovich/dp/073565672X/ref=sr_1_3?keywords=Windows+Sysinternals+Administrator%27s+Reference&qid=1582024887&sr=8-3

Comment: You have a high handle count. Now you know what types of handles have a high count. Now ask yourself whether your code might leak these types of handles somewhere. If you never use Threads, then it's perhaps a 3rd party library.

Comment: Worth the buy. One of the best technical books I read.

Comment: I'll investigate, although I'm not sure out of the three which one is causing the problem.  I know the C++ is using the boost library with smart pointers for threads,  I would imagine the events are internal and semaphores will be the mutex's that are created for the threads...will look into.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

windbg !handle  will provide a summary after displaying individual handles

the summary will show how many handles are there for each type

screenshot below
cmd.exe pid 5124 has 22 handles
the command below  attaches windbg to pid non-invasively executes !handle and quits
gnuwin32-awk filters only the relevant data

```
cdb -pv -c "!handle;q" -p 5124  | awk "/Handles/,/quit/"
```

result

```
:\>cdb -pv -c "!handle;q" -p 5124  | awk "/Handles/,/quit/"
23 Handles
Type            Count
Event           2
File            2
Directory       1
WindowStation   2
Key             10
Process         2
Thread          1
Desktop         1
ALPC Port       2
quit:
```

[image]

Comment: I did mention in my post I'm using Windows 10, so no awk.

Comment: you dont need awk i used awk just to cut the garbage load unload spew you can use -logo to log to a file and use findstr / word / wordpad/ notepad/whatevet  and btw awk is available for windowd