# Understanding HandleCount in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, process

I was trying to understand handles and handle count in python.

I opened a file with python and was expecting the handle count to increase since the file is still open. But the handle count remained the same.

```
C:\Users\achakravarthy>py
Python 3.7.2 (tags/v3.7.2:9a3ffc0492, Dec 23 2018, 23:09:28) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> os.getppid()
12688
```

```
PS C:\Users\achakravarthy> get-process -id 12688 | select-object Handle, HandleCount                                    
Handle HandleCount
------ -----------
  5116         142
```

I opened a file and wrote a text. The file is still open.
I was expecting the handle count to increase to **143** since the process still has the file open.

```
>>> f = open( 'test.txt', 'w+' )
>>> f.write('hello world')
11
```

But HandleCount remains the same (142). The handle value was however changing randomly.

```
PS C:\Users\achakravarthy> get-process -id 12688 | select-object Handle, HandleCount                                    
Handle HandleCount
------ -----------
  1528         142
```

Can someone please help understand/educate with resources on why handlecount does not increase on opening a file and why handle value keeps changing randomly.

Comment: Since, HandleCount is not specific to Python but is a feature of the Windows OS, this may help answer your question. [Windows process handle count continues to grow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60058273/windows-process-handle-count-continues-to-grow)

Comment: @itprorh66 I am curious to understand why opening file does not increase the handle count for the python process since file is opened with python.

Comment: I tested your code and my HandleCount went up

Comment: According to WIN OS, a handle is a unique identifier for an object managed by Windows. It's like a pointer, but not a pointer in the sense that it's not an address that could be dereferenced by user code to gain access to some data. Instead a handle is to be passed to a set of functions that can perform actions on the object the handle identifies.  Depending on the computer activity, handlecounts will change.as resources are allocated and deallocated.  They are not solely determined by the application you are using to get the count.

Comment: @viilpe It does not work for me. I've tried multiple times. Would it be possible to share more details, screenshots ?

Comment: @itprorh66 Yes, but handlecount is simply the number of resources/files allocated/opened to the process right ? In my case via py process I opened a file. But the handlecount didn't increase. The file however is still seen locked.

Comment: handlecount is the number of resources allocated to a process.  These resources can be utilized by the process to open files, allocate memory, or be held in abeyance until needed.  There is no absolute correlation between handlecount and actual resources being used at a point in time. For example, a handle could be assigned to a memory block used for a stack, once the stack is released, the process doesn't have to release the handle, it may hold the handle for later use to prevent overhead associated withb request for new handle.

Comment: @AakashChakravarthy there is nothing special that I can share. I did exactly what you wrote in post. OS win7 x64, Python 3.8.6 x32